# How to backup downloaded Nuget Packages with TeamCity

Tags: .net, nuget, teamcity

My customer would like to keep a local copy of every Nuget package ever used in a project, so that it is possible to build older versions of the application even if nuget.org is not available. The packages are not created in the project, just downloaded using Nuget restore from nuget.org.

It would be great if the packages ended up on a file share on a different server than the one running TeamCity.

A naive approach would be to add a build step, right after the Nuget Installer step,  that copied every .nupkg file to the desired file share. Would this be a good way to solve this, or is there any better way?

Where are the Nuget packages stored on the build agent? Is it possible to reference that folder with some environmental variable or something alike, so that the copy script does not need to have hard coded paths?

Comment: I just realized that the packages can be found in the same folder as my Visual Studio solution. I will have no problem referencing that folder. The question about any better ways to perform this still remains, though.

Answer (score 1):

All downloaded NuGet packages are stored in *%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache*.

If you want to automatically upload those to a file share, I recommend using something like BitTorrent Sync for this. https://www.getsync.com/

Comment: I would prefer only backing up Nuget packages used in this particular VS solution, not every package used by any solution built on this TeamCity server.

Comment: One of the benefits of having your TeamCity server only use NuGet packages from the local repository is that you are still able to build even when nuget.org goes down, which has happened a few times.

Comment: But how would you get the packages to the build server in the first place?

Comment: NuGet automatically restores packages listed in the _packages.config_ file. It will download these packages from the repository list. The default being the Official NuGet.org repository. If you add your local file share as the first repository, that's where NuGet will pull from. By ensuring that all packages are synced from the cache to this repository, you no longer have to worry about the NuGet site being available.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should sync packages from my workstation to the build server? That doesn't sounds right to me. I don't want the build server to depend on a certain workstation.

Comment: You're not really "depending" on the workstation. First of all, a developer (at a workstation) is the one that adds a package to the project. That package is downloaded to the cache. This will then sync to to the file share that the build server uses. You can have multiple workstations all syncing to the same share. The package will already be synced by the time the developer commits the changes for a new build. So your build server doesn't have to fetch any packages at all. Anyway, you asked for an automated way to make packages available to your build server. I'm just giving you an example.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. I would like the build server to download the packages from nuget.org and to back them up for future use. The product we're building is intended to live for several years, so we would like a local copy of all used packages so that it is possible to build the solution again in 5 or 10 years from now, even if the used versions of the packages is no longer available via nuget.org.

Comment: I get that. But I think you're going about it backwards. Anyway, NuGet promises that ALL versions of packages will be available indefinitely. However, it would be simple to to add a Post-Build step that copies the packages folder to a file share for backup purposes.

Comment: Is it possible to have Nuget to fetch packages from multiple sources? In that case maybe I could use my local packages repository as first source, and NuGet.org as second source, so that NuGet fetches packages that is missing in the local repository from nuget.org?

Comment: Yes, that is what the repository sources are for. It's an ordered list.

Comment: Well, I'm not arguing what Nuget promises but my customer would feel better with everything needed to build on his own servers. While I would like to keep the customer satisfied I would like to minimize the manual work on this kind of tasks.